# gcloud cli command shows error INVALID_ARGUMENT when listing assets for project ID for some accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, assets, invalid-argument

gcloud cli throws an error INVALID_ARGUMENT ehen I try to run this command for some accounts.

```
gcloud scc assets list projects/project-id
```

Ths is the exact error that I get,

```
ERROR: (gcloud.scc.assets.list) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

There is no specific way to troubleshoot what exactly is the issue in any documnetations..

Answer (score 0):

What SDK version are you on? I just tested the same gcloud command as you mentioned and had no issues.

gcloud version:

```
Google Cloud SDK 349.0.0
alpha 2021.07.19
beta 2021.07.19
bq 2.0.70
core 2021.07.19
gsutil 4.65
```

Command:

```
gcloud scc assets list projects/my-project-id
```

Comment: Google Cloud SDK 348.0.0,
alpha 2021.07.19,
beta 2021.07.19,
bq 2.0.70,
core 2021.07.19,
gsutil 4.65.. But this works fine for my RnD account.. Only for some accounts the same gcloud command throws an error INVALID_ARGUMENT..

Comment: Could you update to the [most recent version](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#34900_2021-07-20) and try again?

Comment: Updated to the latest version - Google Cloud SDK 350.0.0. But still throws the same error "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Security Command Center Legacy, which is disabled according to the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/legacy-products-migration).

> Security Command Center Legacy, previously known as Cloud Security Command Center, and Event Threat Detection Legacy have been permanently disabled. For information on upgrading to Security Command Center Standard or Premium, see Migrate from legacy Security Command Center products. To inquire about flexible pricing options for the Premium tier, complete our inquiry form. You should receive a response within two US business days.

I suggest you to migrate your account to [Security Command Center Standard or Premium](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/legacy-products-migration).